# Degrees of freedom in lme4 models

Tags: lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

How are Kenwood-Rodger degrees of freedom approximated in lme4 models?

In particular, I am interested in a model of the form:

`response ~ continuous.predictor1 + continuous.predictor2 + (1|grouping.factor)`